# How can I determine what data source is being used in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC.  I created a new web app, and I'm using the pre-built authentication tool that comes with a new MVC site.  It has all the pretty little Register and Log In functionality and all that, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly ties the application TO the data source.  I come from web forms application development, so in my experience, you set the data source in the web.config file, them create the connection.  I've wired my web.config file to my local database, but I can't figure out what exactly my app is using to determine what tables/fields to look in.

I've traced the pre-built Register view to the RegisterViewModel class model.  From there, I'm not sure where to go.  I'm not sure where to tell it to look in my tblUsers table to do the authentication...  I'm at a loss.  I'm assuming that Microsoft has bundled the authentication templates in the app creation because there are benefits to using THEIR method, but... am I going about this all wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly I suggest you watch some tutorials from here http://www.asp.net/mvc. The datasource by default is your localDB you can change it to your own MS-SQL server. Refer this for connection strings https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/ . 
If you want to see your data in localDb login to your sql management studio. Assuming its ms-sql 2012 ServerName: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Windows Authentication you will see a datbase with your project name and some tables created by default for authentication.
Model represents your sql tables. ViewModels are for displaying your models in the view. View is basically tied to an action method in your contoller, Each controller is the link between your view and your model.

Step 1: Define your model class. This will be your table

```
public class Person 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Step 2: Define your Context. You will use this to query database
DbContext is your link between Sql and your application

```
public class MyContext : Dbcontext
{
  public MyContext():base("Database"){} // Name defined in web.config

  public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; } //Letting context know your model
}
```

Step 3. Use MyContext to query your db

In your controller or repository you can use it by instantiating your context

private MyContext db = new MyContext();

Comment: So, the only connection string in my web.config file is the one I created for my SQL db.  I'm essentially trying to change it so that it looks in my User table.  The pre-built authentication utility it created (I'm using MVC 5 by the way) is using the RegisterViewModel model.  That contains the properties that are being used by the controller... are you saying that in my LocalDb (which I can't find... there isn't a database file in the App_Data folder) there's a tabe called RegisterViewModel?  I'm starting to think I should start from scratch and generate my own authentication methods.

Comment: Do you have microsoft sql server management studio? If you have login with the details ServerName: (LocalDb)\v11.0 and windows authentication. Or you can go to server explorer in VS, click on connect to database and get it that way. Think what you are missing is you need to click on show all files on your solution explorer. If you still cant find the mdf file, run the application try to login with any test username and pwd. This is because it will create db only on the first query to the db. So, get back to solutions explorer try to find the mdf file under App_Data, hit refresh if u dont see

Comment: Right click on the mdf file under App_Data and open. Main thing to notice is show all files on solutions explorer, and other thing is you need to query the db i.e. by trying to log in which will generate the db.

Comment: I will try the "show all files."  But essentially, my goal is to alter their prebuilt Authentication structure so that it points to my use table.  Should I import/create a reference to my database (which has existed since before creation of the site) in the project and do it that way?

Comment: Basically all the connections to db are done in web.config. Oh i see.. so you want to do Code First development targeting an existing database. You need to reverse engineer your database here is the link to do it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx